# How can I create tiled Shaded Relief rasters from tiled DTM rasters, while avoiding edge artifacts?

Tags: r, terra

I have a series of DTM tiles from which I'd like to create Shaded Relief tiles with the same extent. I am trying to make use of the Virtual Raster Dataset in Terra. The tiles are loaded into a VRT and a window is defined that extends slightly past the tile extent... i.e., the expanded virtual tile is processed and not the actual tile. A loop allows each tile to be processed.

My problem is that I don't think I'm understanding VRT as I've set up `terrain` and `shade` with the expanded window. The result is a set of tiles with gaps between them.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# create shaded relief from .vrt
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
library(terra)

# Create a random digital terrain model
dtm <- rast(nlyr = 1, xmin = 270000, xmax = 280000, ymin = 5530000, ymax = 5540000, resolution = 100, crs = "EPSG:23032")
dtm <- init(dtm, fun = runif) * 10

# Tile the DTM
tiles <- rast(ncols = 2, nrows = 2, extent = dtm)
filename <- paste0("d:/Temp/", "dtm_tile_.tif")
makeTiles(dtm, tiles, filename)
dtmTiles <- list.files(path = "D:/Temp",
                       pattern = "tif$",
                       full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE)

# Make a Virtual Raster Dataset from the tiles.
# The purpose of the VRT is hopefully to be able to include parts of the adjacent tiles.
# The expanded virtual tile can be used to create a Shaded Relief, and then cropped to the actual tile.
for (i in dtmTiles) {
  myVrt <- terra::vrt(x = dtmTiles)
  dtmName <- basename(i)
  shdName <- gsub("dtm_tile", "shdRlf", dtmName)
  dtmPath <- dirname(i)
  shdFile <- paste0(dtmPath, "/", shdName)

  # to avoid artifacts, extend the VRT window.
  e <- ext(rast((i)))
  extend(e, 200)
  window(myVrt) <- e

  # process dtm derivatives based on the VRT window.
  slope <- terrain(myVrt, "slope", unit="radians")
  aspect <- terrain(myVrt, "aspect", unit="radians")
  shdRlf <- shade(slope, aspect, 45, 315)

  # crop back to the tile extents.
  crop(shdRlf, ext(rast(i))) 
  writeRaster(shdRlf, shdFile)
}
```